# Perform special kind of initialization of string in C

Tags: c

As you know in C, we can initialize string variables like this:

```
char text[1024] = 
"Hello "
"World";
```

But what if I have a function that returns the word "World"?

```
char text[1024] =
"Hello "
World();
```

It seems to me that's not possible in C.
Please confirm.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can only concatenate string literals using this approach.

Comment: @CoolGuy I need that into initialization part. Question is closed.

Comment: @alk um what? you definitely can…

Comment: Oopss, sure seems I sufferd a temporary brain-lapse... @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant example of function call as initialization? I don' t clearly undestand what you are talking about.

Comment: Please show us how `World()` is declared.

Comment: @UnhandledException `int foo = do_stuff();`

Comment: What's to stop you from putting `strncpy(..., world())` (or `snprintf(...)` to merge several strings) into `main`? You want the assignment done at runtime, not compile time, don't you?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I mean for strings. char text[1024] = SuperMegaInitializationFunction(); it's not possible.

Comment: @UnhandledException no, it's not, but it's not because of the function, it's because of the array.

Comment: function call is not allowed in that part, right?

Comment: @UnhandledException it absolutely is. again, it's ***NOT because of the function call.*** It's because you can only initialize an array with an initializer list. If it weren't an array, it would have been perfectly fine to use a function call as the initializer expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

The L-value to the assigment operator needs to be modifyable, which an array isn't.

From the C11-Standard:

> **6.5.16/2**
>
> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

The only exception to this is during initialisation when using literals as R-value:

```
char text[1024] = "Hello ""World";
```

From the C11-Standard:

> **6.7.9/14**
>
> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

If `World()` is something that always returns "World", then define it as a macro:

```
#define World "World"
```

And then do:

```
char text[1024] =
"Hello "
World;  //Without parentheses
```

**EDIT**

String concatenation in the way you expect to do is made by the C preprocessor.You are actually looking for a runtime concatenation of two strings, which can be performed in multiple ways. The simplest one is achieved by `strcat` function, but the initialization should be performed explicitly by a function:

```
char text[1024];
void init_text() {
    strcpy(text, "Hello ");
    strcat(text, World());  //World() defined somewhere else
}
```

Alternative using `sprintf` :

```
void init_text() {
    sprintf(text, "Hello %s", World());
}
```

Then in the `main` function, call `init_text()` at the beginning:

```
int main() {
    init_text();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Other ideas about how to use World() function that returns char * inside of initializer?

Comment: Just to be paranoid, how about using `strncat` and `snprintf` instead of their unbound versions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in standard C to initialize something with some runtime specific behavior. So the standard portable way is to initialize the data by calling a function at the beginning of `main`, as [answered by Claudix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077178/841108).

However, if you are using some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) you could otherwise, on some systems (including Linux and probably other POSIX systems), use some [constructor attribute on function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). So you would declare:

```
  static void init_text(void) __attribute__((constructor));
```

and define `init_text` like in [Claudix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077178/841108) *without* having to call it in your `main`  : since it has the `constructor` attribute, it would be called magically before `main`, or during [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) if it appears inside a dynamically linked plugin or library.

A more portable trick might be to have a function returning that text which will initialize it during its first call. So instead of using `text` you would call `get_my_text()` everywhere (perhaps by putting `#define text get_my_text()` in a header, but I don't recommend doing so for readability reasons, so replace every occurrence of `text` by `get_my_text()` ...), and define it as:

```
  const char*get_my_text() {
    static char textbuf[1024];
    if (textbuf[0]) {
      // already initialized, so return it
      return textbuf;
    };
    snprintf(textbuf, sizeof(textbuf), "Hello %s", World());
    return textbuf;
 }
```

<sup>Beware that such a trick is not reliable in multi-threaded programs: two threads might run `get_my_text` exactly at the same time, and you have a data [race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). In a multi-threaded app use e.g. [pthread_once](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_once.html)</sup>

You could even define `get_my_text` as a `static inline` function in your header file.

<sup>PS Always prefer [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to `sprintf` to avoid [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Also notice that in standard C++ any `static` or global data with some given [constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) is initialized *before* `main` ... hence the name of GCC function attribute...</sup>